# Jmeter loop through CSV file

Tags: loops, jmeter

I have a test plan where I use 2 CSV files.

```
CSV1:
USER1
USER2
USER3
.
.
USERN
```

```
CSV2:
VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE3
.
.
.
VALUEN
```

I run the test with 3 threads (in this example).

Scenario:

```
log in
    loop 5 times:
        1. search value
        2. open value
        3. close value
```

**Expected Result:**
Each user searches a different value, each time and no value is searched more than 1 time by users. This means that if USER1 searched for VALUE1, than no other user can search for VALUE1 anymore and USER1 will search,open and save VALUE1 only 1 time and than continue to a new value

**Actual Result:**

```
USER 1 loops through value1 5 times
USER 2 loops through value2 5 times
USER 3 loops through value3 5 times
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you set the "Sharing mode" to "All threads" (which is default), you should get what you are expecting. To get what you are stating, you have to set the "Sharing mode" to current thread.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config